# How to expand a string capacity without using realloc()?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I was trying to figure a way to expand a string capacity without using `realloc`. for example what is the major difference between this code:

```
void insert(char *dest, char *src, int pos){

    char *temp = malloc(strlen(dest)+strlen(src)+1);

    /*
    malloc failure handling
    */

    strcpy(temp,dest);
    //rest of code

}
```

and:

```
void insert(char *dest, char *src, int pos){

    char *temp =(char*)realloc(dest,strlen(dest)+strlen(src)+1);
    /*
    realloc failure handling
    */

    dest = temp;
    //rest of code

}
```

or is there any better way to do it?

note that both `src` and `dest` are intialized using `malloc`.

Comment: Maybe a linked list.  Probably can't use `string.h` operations.

Comment: Both codes do more or less the same thing, but they are flawed anyway, the caller of `insert` will never see the new pointer. In C variables are passed by value. Actually `realloc` does basically this: 1. allocate the new size. 2. copy content of old buffer to newly allocated memory. 3. free the old buffer. What's the problem with realloc? We need more context information. Basically you can't do it without using some form of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: "*the major difference*" is that the 2nd snippet needlessly casts the result of the allocation function which returns `void*`! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `malloc --> memcpy --> free` in fact is what `realloc` conceptually does, just only somewhat optimised.

And because of this optimisation this question

> *what is the major difference between this code*

can be answered by saying, that the former could be faster and more efficient in terms of memory fragmentation.

---

> *How to expand a string capacity without using realloc()?*

*If* VLA's* are available (which were not before C99 and perhaps in C11 and never in C++) *and* you know the maximum size of input *and* **this size would never lead to a stack overflow** then and **only** then you *could* do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

...

  char s1[] = "123";
  char s2[] = "456";
  char s3[] = "789";
  char s[strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + 1];

  strcpy(s, s1);
  strcat(s, s2);
  strcat(s, s3);

  puts(s);
```

and will see

```
123456789
```

All in all if starting playing with `malloc()` there is no reason to not as well turn to its cousin `realloc()`.

Comment: thanks. I also assume strcpy() is better than memcpy() for string managment, which is why i avoided using realloc in the first place

Comment: The VLA approach is a **really really** bad idea, and I retracted an initial upvote based on it. As written, it works with the string hard-coded, but with any of them being uncontrolled input, it's a stack overflow/expoitable stack-clash bug waiting to happen. Correct use of VLA is very subtle, rarely applicable, and doesn't belong in an answer to someone who seems to be just learning the language.

Comment: @R.. I already had a somewhat bad feeling when writing this, but ... well ... just ignored it. You are so right. Need to think about what to do now, as it even got accepted ...

Comment: @Ashes: "*assume strcpy() is better than memcpy() for string managment, which is why i avoided using realloc* err what? You avoided `realloc()` exactly why?

Comment: @alk mainly to avoid `realloc` failures, but also my probleme involves copying only the first `i` characters from `dest`,  so i'm planning to use `strncpy()` instead. sorry for not making it clear.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` is equivalent to

```
void *my_realloc(void *old_p, size_t new_size) {
   void *new_p = malloc(new_size);
   if (!new_p)
      return NULL;

   size_t old_size = ...;
   if (old_size < new_size)
      memcpy(new_p, old_p, old_size);
   else
      memcpy(new_p, old_p, new_size);

   free(old_p);
   return new_p;
}
```

Except that `realloc` may extend or shrink the existing memory block. This will save it from having to copy the bytes from the old location into the new location.

This means that `realloc` is at least as quick as `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free`, but possibly more so.

Comment: ... and `realloc` may also _shrink_ the existing memory block.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Indeed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that a good realloc implementation would do optimizations and skip the copy if possible. (It can be like check if there is contiguos free space in memory to enlarge your allocation, but this depends on how the memory is managed).

There is no better solution than realloc if you don't want to write some sort of memory management to handle strings of undefined length at runtime.